# Copy the first 2 lines from a file and then remove the lines

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I need to process a file using a shell script. The file arrives with the data as well as some embedded information releavant to how it is processed.
The file is in the following format;

- email_address
- system_area
- item_number
- item_number
- item_number
- item_number
- and so on ...

The email_address is required to notify the user submitting the file that it has completed and the system_area indicates to the loading process where the file should be loaded. Therefore I am taking both these values into variables for use in the script.
I am currently using 3 sed commands to get the info and then remove the lines;

```
var1=$(sed -n '1p' infile)
var2=$(sed -n '2p' infile)
sed -i '1,2d' infile
```

The above code works but I feel it is 'clumsy' and probably inefficient.
Does anyone know of a way to achieve the same ends more elegantly/efficiently ?

Comment: `{ read -r var1 ; read -r var2 ; } < infile` Regarding 3rd command I am not sure to understand it purpose: you intend to do with remaining lines something else?

Comment: @Costas - The third line is intended to remove lines 1 and 2 from the file ready to be processed. I used sed -i to perform an 'inplace' edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is quite ok, I'd probably do that as a quick solution. It's more efficient to actually exit sed immediately after printing: `sed -n '1{p;q}'` to avoid reading the entire file for no reason.

Now the most awkward part is reading the file twice to get first two lines. You could simply use shell builtins:

```
{ read -r var1; read -r var2; } < infile
```

and then either keep `sed -i '1,2d'` or simply use `tail -n +3 > outfile; mv outfile infile`.

The ultimate way of doing this in one single pass is to read the two variables with `read` and then cat the rest:

```
{ read -r var1; read -r var2; cat; } < infile > outfile
```

Note that I'm saving the output into another file (and then you can possibly copy it back). That's not as "elegant" as inplace modification with `sed`, but it is safer, and it does the same amount of writing. This last version also only reads the file once, not three times.

Comment: I like this approach but can't seem to get it to work. If I wrap the reads in {} then 'read' is not found. If I wrap in () then no errors but the assignment of the var isn't made. A straight read -r var1 < infile DOES work.Not sure what the {} does but I know that () will invoke as a sub shell. I would like to use the read method for variables with the sed for removal. It feels 'nicer'.

Comment: Which shell are you using? `read` is a shell builtin, it should be available from everywhere, so there must be a syntax error somewhere. Just be careful about the last semicolon inside the braces. Don't skip it, it's important. The `{}` syntax is just command grouping, it's not launching a new shell -- this is why the variables stay set.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem suddenly occurred to me; you need spaces after a { and before a }. That makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that `var1` and `var2` will get same value.

I would use

```
 var1=$(awk 'NR==1' infile)
 var2=$(awk 'NR==2' infile)
 sed -i '1,2d' infile
```

where

- `NR` is an awk variable meaning Number of Record, that is the line number.
- `NR==1` select line 1
- default awk action is to print the whole line